# jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest cause nginx proxy 500 for https

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I am trying to use `jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest` for proxy reverse.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`, it works for http, but failed fot https.

When access `https://web.test.cn`, it return 500 error.

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    test-proxy:
        image: "jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest"
        container_name: "test-proxy"
        volumes:
            - "html:/usr/share/nginx/html"
            - "dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam"
            - "vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d"
            - "certs:/etc/nginx/certs"
            - "/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
        restart: "always"
        networks: 
            - "test-net"
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
    test-certs:
        image: "jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:latest"
        container_name: "test-certs"
        volumes:
            - "html:/usr/share/nginx/html"
            - "dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam"
            - "vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d"
            - "certs:/etc/nginx/certs"
            - "/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
        environment:
            NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER: "test-proxy"
            DEFAULT_EMAIL: "xx@hotmail.com"
        restart: "always"
        depends_on:
            - "test-proxy"
        networks: 
            - "test-net"
    test-web:
        container_name: 'test-web'
        image: 'xx/test:web-v1.0.0'
        ports: 
            - "8888:80"
            - "8889:443"
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV=production
          - VIRTUAL_HOST=web.test.cn
        #volumes:
        #  - ./test-web/:/usr/share/nginx/html
        networks: 
            - "test-net"       
        expose:
          - "80"
          - "443"
    test-server:
        container_name: 'test-server'
        image: 'myhub/test:server-v1.0.0'
        restart: always
        working_dir: '/app'
        ports: 
            - "8886:80"
            - "8887:443"
        volumes: 
        #    - ./test-server/:/app
            - ./test-certificates/https:/https/
        environment: 
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=server.test.cn
            - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
            - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=server
            - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/server.test.cn.pfx
        entrypoint: 
            ["dotnet", "test.Mango.Web.Host.dll"]    
        networks: 
            - "test-net"       
        depends_on: 
            - test-mysql
            #- test-chrome
    #test-chrome:
    #    container_name: 'test-chrome'
    #    image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
    #    shm_size: 200m
    #    restart: always
    #    ports: 
    #         - "8886:4444"
    test-mysql:
        container_name: 'test-mysql'
        image: 'mysql'
        restart: always
        environment: 
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 'MangoDb'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'dbpassword'
            MYSQL_USER: 'test'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'dbpassword'
        ports: 
          - "8880:3306"
        networks: 
            - "test-net"
        volumes: 
           - ./test-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
    certs:
    html:
    vhost:
    dhparam:
networks:
    test-net:
        external: true
```

I reference [500 Internal Server Error #689](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/acme-companion/issues/689), and get the same nginx config below

```
# web.test.cn
upstream web.test.cn {
        ## Can be connected with "test-net" network
        # test-web
        server 172.19.0.3:80;
}
server {
        server_name web.test.cn;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://web.test.cn;
        }
}
server {
        server_name web.test.cn;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 500;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/default.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/default.key;
}
```

But, not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I made many commits and generated letsencrypt certificates over 50 times. Therefore, they were no longer created for the domain, but I did not understand it right away. So if someone with such an error as yours will most likely encounter a problem in the limit for a free certificate - 50 per week

Comment: https://www.singularaspect.com/use-nginx-proxy-and-letsencrypt-companion-to-host-multiple-websites/  - this instruction is 100% working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What if one is going to use commercial certificates instead of LE?